# Adding +2 to a range of cells in Google Sheets every 24 hours

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

first time posting so forgive me if I don't have a bunch of code to show as I am very new. I want Google Sheets to add 2 to a number in range of cells every 24 hours. For example, I have cells K2:K50 that have various numbers in them ranging from 100-100000; every 24 hours, I want +2 to be added to every cell, so as the days go by it counts up by 2. Is there a way to do this?  Thanks.

I have tried googling and see that a time-driven trigger would be needed but it is telling me a function is needed and I am unsure of exactly how to "write?" the code/function necessary.

Comment: You might consider to use of the Class Range method offset()

Answer (score 0):

To get you started, go to the script editor

[image]

And in Code.gs type in this script

```
function add2Column() {
  let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  let range = sheet.getRange("K2:K50");
  let values = range.getValues();
  values.forEach( row => row[0] = row[0]+2 );
  range.setValues(values);
}
```

Then from the script editor go to Triggers

[image]

And build your time based trigger

[image]

References

- [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)
- [Spreadsheet.getSheetByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String))
- [Sheet.getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(String))
- [Range.getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())
- [Range.setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object))
- [Array.forEach()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp)
- [Arrow function =>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)